# How do I compare two text files that have the same information but are not in order?

Tags: python-2.7

Preface: Im very new to scripting/programming and I am using this as a learning tool that will be helpful for work.

I made a small python 2.7 script to run a daily nmap ping scan to see if my servers are up and running.

The script works fine, but my final comparison is failing because of the lag of the servers replying, it ends up making the list different from the baseline list for comparison.

For instance:

Baseline.txt has the following info

```
Host:10.0.1.2 status up
Host:10.0.1.3 status up
Host:10.0.1.4 status up
Host:10.0.1.5 status up
```

When the script runs, the following is returned due to lag:

```
Host:10.0.1.5 status up
Host:10.0.1.2 status up
Host:10.0.1.4 status up
Host:10.0.1.3 status up
```

The information is the same, but with the order being different, the script sees the two files as different, and reports that a change has occurred. (Im using a simple if statement for the comparison, which may be my issue)

Is there a way to iterate each line of the file, compare it to each line of the baseline file, and if the information is there, have it read it as no change? Or am I doing it wrong completely?

Here is the code if it is needed:

```
import smtplib

#Method for emailing if a problem arises
def notify():

    SMTP_SERVER = 'smtp.gmail.com'
    SMTP_PORT = 587

    sender = 'SERVER_ALERT@company.com'
    recipient = 'me@me.com'
    subject = 'SERVER STATUS ALERT'
    body = 'Check all servers for an unscheduled change!'

    body = "" + body + ""

    headers = ["From: " + sender,
       "Subject: " + subject, 
       "To: " + recipient, 
       "MIME-Version: 1.0",
       "Content-Type: text/html"]
    headers = "\r\n".join(headers)

    session = smtplib.SMTP(SMTP_SERVER, SMTP_PORT)
    session.ehlo()
    session.starttls()
    session.login('notify_me@me.com', 'password')

    session.sendmail(sender, recipient, headers + "\r\n\r\n" + body)
    session.quit()

#Scanning with nmap and naming the scan the date
timestr = time.strftime("%m-%d-%y")

daily_scan = open(timestr+".txt", 'w')

os.system("nmap -sn -iL ip_list.txt -oG scan.txt")

scan_data = open("scan.txt", 'r').readlines()

#Checking for changes
for line in scan_data:
    if "Host:" in line:
        daily_scan.write(str(line))

daily_scan.close()

os.system('rm scan.txt')

baseline = open('baseline.txt', 'r').readlines()

daily_check = open(timestr+".txt", 'r').readlines()

if baseline == daily_check:
    exit()
else:
    notify()
```

Comment: `os.system('rm scan.txt')` => `os.remove("scan.txt")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> b = open('baseline.txt').readlines()
>>> r = open('return.txt').readlines()
>>> b == sorted(r)
True
```

To program defensively, in case of some future change to the code left baseline.txt unsorted, we could use this test instead:

```
sorted(b) == sorted(r)
```

In the end, you will likely want something more informative than that simple equality test.  Consider:

```
problems = [ line for line in r if line not in b ]
if problems:
    notify()
else:
    exit()
```

This assigns to `problems` any changes from the baseline, in other words, any lines in `r` that do not also appear unchanged in `b`.  This code does not depend on sorting.  If there are no lines in problems, then it evaluates to false and the code exits.  If any lines in `r` differ, then `notify` is called.  To provide more informative output, you could pass the list of `problems` to `notify`.

Comment: Sorry, I mistook a 4 for a 1.

Comment: @larsmans It was, regardless, a good thing to consider.  I added it to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like if you replace your last line with

```
if sorted(baseline) == sorted(daily_check):
    exit()
```

You could get what you want.